# regex group isn't working for multiple addressses

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I have a problem with my regex. I have to read a file with contacts data and import it into a database. The line has a standard format and I am able to read all the lines, extract contact name, street/housenr., zip and city. I have the problem that the housenumber can be either a number or like this '7/9'.

Because my regex expect only number, the import for second alternative does not work cause of the slash. another problem is that the city can have also a slash when the name of the city consists of two parts.

```
String addressPattern = "^" 
                      + "(?<street>(?:\\p{L}| |\\d|\\.|-)+?) "
                      + "(?<number>\\d+(?: ?- \\// ?\\d+)? *[a-zA-Z]?) "
                      + "(?<zip>\\d{5}) "
                      + "(?<city>(?:\\p{L}| |-)+)"
                      + "(?: *\\((?<suffix>[^\\)]+)\\))?" + "$";
```

Regex : `^(?<street>(?:\p{L}| |\d|\.|-)+?) (?<number>\d+(?: ?- ?\d+)? *[a-zA-Z]?) (?<zip>\d{5}) (?<city>(?:\p{L}| |-)+)(?: *\((?<suffix>[^\)]+)\))?$`

Here is the address part.

1. `First Street 32 78224 firstCity`
2. `Second Street 7/9 73430 secondCity`
3. `Third Street 32 78224 third/City`
4. `Fourth Street 9/7 73430 fourth/city`

The first and the third examples are OK. I can read the data. But the second and the fourth return empty string.

Can someone maybe help me?

Comment: Can you share the specification of all the 4 (or 5) parts ?

Comment: Are regexen the proper tool for your task? Addresses may contain addendums like `Harlow House` or `Suite 1234`, street numbers may be suffixed like `69a`, there may be no street name at all ( eg. `12 99999 Backwater` ); in the German city of Mannheim, no street names exist downtown but blocks are referenced by a kind of coordinate code (eg. `Q3 12345 city`. Ok, it's extreme ...). These outliers to 'common' formats would break your code but be very hard to spot beforehand unless you have a very good test coverage (not to mention that supporting them blows up your regex disproportionately)

Answer (score 0):

I would see an easier regex : `^(?<street>\D*)\s(?<number>[\d\/]+)\s(?<zip>\d{5})\s(?<city>.*)$`

- `street` is anything except digit
- `number` is digits/slash
- `zip` is 5 digits
- `city` is the rest

This matches well your 4 strings : [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pv5TLC/1)

Comment: The `street` pattern would falter for phrases like `82nd Street`, ie. hi ordinals in street names.

Comment: @collapsar right, i'm just following the OP requirement, his concerns seems to be about 'street number zip city', he should give the exact specification

Comment: Yes he should, and yes, it was just a minor detail, but I suspected the OP would not have thought of.

Answer (score 0):

You might make use of optional groups:

```
^(?<street>[\pL\pN.]+(?:\h+[\pL\pN.]+)*)\h+(?<number>\d+(?:/\d+)?)\h+(?<zip>\d{5})\h+(?<city>\pL+)(?<suffix>/\pL+)?$
```

**About the pattern**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?<street>`

  - `[\pL\pN.]+` Match 1+ times any of the listed
  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `\h+[\pL\pN.]+` Match 1+ times any of the listed
  - `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times
- `)\h+` Close street group, match 1+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `(?<number>`

  - `\d+(?:/\d+)?` Match 1+ digits with an optional `/` number part
- `)\h+` Close number group, match 1+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `(?<zip>`

  - `\d{5}` Match 5 digits
- `)\h+` Close zip group, match 1+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `(?\pL+) Match city
- `(?<suffix>/\pL+)?` Match optional suffix
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LD9dde/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/HwLaA4)

In Java

```
String regex = "^(?<street>[\\pL\\pN.]+(?:\\h+[\\pL\\pN.]+)*)\\h+(?<number>\\d+(?:/\\d+)?)\\h+(?<zip>\\d{5})\\h+(?<city>\\pL+)(?<suffix>/\\pL+)?$";
```